# Converting PHP preg_replace to htaccess rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need to create a 301 redirect rule that will match/replace underscores _ with dashes - and remove the trailing .html. The URLs could have any number of underscores _ which is making this difficult for me.

In PHP I can do this as such:

```
$subject = 'this_is_a_bad_url.html';    
$pattern = array('/(_)/', '/.html/');
$replace = array('-', '');
$output = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $subject);
//$output would result to 'this-is-a-bad-url'
```

How would I write this in .htaccess?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: @John I really don't know where to start using multiple replacements in one regex :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
  Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*?)_(.*?)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^  /%1-%2 [R,L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*?).html$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^  /%1 [R,L]
```